# Nodejs express interchangeable session stores

Tags: node.js, session, express

Is there a way to switch session stores on the fly with express?

Currently depending on default config my express app is using either redis or mongo to store sessions.

So my question: is there a way to switch session from using redis to mongo on the fly? In case if redis goes down.

I tried calling `app.use(express_session({....}))` again but it doest work. I think there must me some hook that will allow me to delete current session store and create|add new one. Not sure where though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to "un-use" a mounted middleware after the app has started, but what you could do is write your own session store (a pretty simple api to follow) that handles switching between the two (or more) stores.

Comment: Hmm thats an idea. But sounds like a whole new project! (i was secretly hoping for simpler faster solution.. ha)

Comment: It's really not that bad, I've done a custom session store before. The hard part will be in deciding which to use and how to maintain someone's session when you have to switch. Likely, you'll end up storing all sessions in each listed provider, then providing it back again if any of them respond.  Just keepign it sync'd will be the main task for your code.